# p:dialog don'nt show buttons when maximize

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I have the next issue with a p:dialog in a xhtml. In this p:dialog I have 3 buttons in the bottom of the dialog. The code is:

```
<p:dialog header="window" minimizable="true" maximizable="true" width="800" height="500" modal="true">
    <p:outputPanel>
        <p:panelGrid columns="1">
            <p:dataGrid columns="1" var="var" layout="grid">
                <p:panel style="text-align: justify;">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="##{fila + 1}"/>
                        <p:outputPanel style="float:right;">
                            <h:outputText value="reter"/>

                            <h:outputText value="fdsfds" >
                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:panelGrid columns="1" >
                        <h:outputText value="gefdgdf" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </p:dataGrid>
            <p:row>
                <br/>
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="gdfgdf" />
                </p:column>
            </p:row>            
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:outputPanel>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:outputPanel style="float:right;">
            <p:commandLink >
                <i class="fa fa-comment-o fa-2x"/>
            </p:commandLink>
            <p:commandLink >
                <i class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-2x"/>
            </p:commandLink>
            <p:commandLink >
                <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x"/>             
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </f:facet>
</p:dialog>
```

When I maximize the dialog, the buttons (`f:facet name="footer"`) don't show it. Why?